# is there a Java equivalent to Javascript's "some" method?

Tags: java, javascript, collections, guava

I have a collection and I would like to know if at least one element meets some condition.  Essentially, what [some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) does in JavaScript, I would like to do on a collection!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Check out [Guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/)'s [`Iterables`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/v11.0.1/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Iterables.html) class and its [`any()`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/v11.0.1/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Iterables.html#any%28java.lang.Iterable,%20com.google.common.base.Predicate%29) implementation.

More or less the same thing as the Commons Collections example in the other answer, but genericized:

```
List<String> strings = Arrays.asList("ohai", "wat", "fuuuu", "kthxbai");
boolean well = Iterables.any(strings, new Predicate<String>() {
    @Override public boolean apply(@Nullable String s) {
        return s.equalsIgnoreCase("fuuuu");
    }
});
System.out.printf("Do any match? %s%n", well ? "Yep" : "Nope");
```

Comment: +1 The lack of generics is a major drawback of commons collections.

Comment: @Anony-Mousse Yeah; it's a pain, although I still use it too :/

Answer (score 24):

As of Java 8, you can convert the Collection into a Stream and use [anyMatch](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#anyMatch-java.util.function.Predicate-) as in the following example.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class SomeExample {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, -6, 7);
        boolean hasNegative = list.stream().anyMatch(x -> x < 0);
        if (hasNegative) {
            System.out.println("List contains some negative number");
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("List does not contain any negative number");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`CollectionUtils`](http://commons.apache.org/collections/api-release/org/apache/commons/collections/CollectionUtils.html) from Apache [commons-collections](http://commons.apache.org/collections/):

```
List<Integer> primes = Arrays.asList(3, 5, 7, 11, 13)
CollectionUtils.exists(primes, even);  //false
```

Where `even` is a predicate:

```
Predicate even = new Predicate() {
    public boolean evaluate(Object object) {
        return ((Integer)object) % 2 == 0;
    }
}
```

Or in an inlined version:

```
List<Integer> primes = Arrays.asList(2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13)
CollectionUtils.exists(primes, new Predicate() {
    public boolean evaluate(Object object) {
        return ((Integer)object) % 2 == 0;
    }
});
```

Yes, it **is** ugly for two reasons:

1. Java does not (yet) support functions as first-class citizens, which are emulated with Single-Abstract-Method interface.
2. `commons-collections` does not support generics.

---

On the other hand in modern JVM languages like Scala you can write:

```
List(3,5,7,11,13,17).exists(_ % 2 == 0)
```

Comment: Another third-party library to support this method is Google Guava, it has [`Iterables.any()`](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/tags/release08/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Iterables.html).

Comment: And Guava supports generics.  ;)

Comment: Java 8 will have lambdas. Also, SAM classes are now called functional interfaces.

Comment: CollectionUtils.exists is now deprecated. Try [anyMatch](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51342789/10205096) in the answer above.

Answer (score 0):

Java doesn't have this feature built-in. [Javascript's `some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) accepts a function pointer as an argument, which is not something that's natively supported in Java. But it should be fairly straight forward to emulate the functionality of [`some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) in Java using a loop and and an interface for the callback functionality.

Comment: It accepts a function, but this is not the same thing as a function pointer.